# NgModel with reactive forms deprecated

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Angular states that certain directives/features are deprecated and may be removed in a future version.

My hypothetical scenario: I use NgModel with reactive forms, to which angular marks as deprecated and may be removed in a future version. Does this mean that this will no longer work in the future, and break my hosted application, even though it may not be running on the latest angular version? Or is the feature just no longer available for future releases and continues to work as normal on versions previous to the version in which it was removed?

Comment: It will work for your older version. but when you upgrade you project to latest version any time soon then you have to change your code according to new features.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yup if got removed in future never update your packages or if you do so then migrate your APP, maybe some migration process will be provided by Angular Team which they do so or you have to upgrade your APP by yourself if doesn't work after the update of your packages